# Server.MapPath and spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, server.mappath

I noticed something weird in Server.MapPath(). If I have a folder with a space at the end I get:

> HttpException: Failed to map the path.

This works fine:
`Server.MapPath("/Folder1/Folder2/item.jpg")`

This works fine:
`Server.MapPath("/Folder1/ Folder2/item.jpg")`

This works fine:
`Server.MapPath("/Folder1/Fol der2/item.jpg")`

This fails!:
`Server.MapPath("/Folder1/Folder2 /item.jpg")`

Could somebody explain to me why a space at the end fails while a space anywhere else doesn't?

**Note:** None of the folders exist.

Comment: Are you sure you get the exception on the Server.MapPath or does the exception happen when you try to access the file?

Comment: It definitely happens in Server.MapPath

Comment: hey check my edited answer you wil find something interesting....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you [shouldn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#file_and_directory_names):

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable to specify a period as the first character of a name. For example, ".temp".

The issue comes from the method `FileUtil.IsSuspiciousPhysicalPath(string physicalPath, out bool pathTooLong)`, which does a compare:

```
string.Compare(physicalPath, Path.GetFullPath(physicalPath), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0;
```

`Path.GetFullPath()` will trim trailing spaces from directory and file names (because it calls `Path.NormalizePath()` which does so), which can be discovered calling `Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Foo \Bar.txt")` for example. Since that won't match the original path that contains the spaces, the method will return `true` thus identifying the path as suspicious, after which `Server.MapPath` will throw the exception.

Comment: Interesting. They don't say anything about leading spaces. That's really weird since Windows removes leading spaces when you create a file/folder. You would expect that hey at least say something about it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The MapPath method maps the specified relative or virtual path to the corresponding physical directory on the server. The method does not check whether the path it returns is valid or exists on the server. You must use Directory.Exists() or File.Exists() method to check if directory or file already exists.

```
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(file))
```

Furthermore, also know following are invlid characters for the method:

Asterisk (*) 
Question mark (?) 
Angle brackets (< or >) 
Comma (,) 
Colon or semi-colon (: or ;) 
Single-quote or double-quote (' or ") 
Right square bracket (]) 
Double slashes (// or \)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, none of the folders in my post exist and none of them throws an exception except the last one. Your answer doesn't explain why.

Comment: Because Server.MapPath() method does not check if directory or file already exists. It just maps the path.

Comment: If it doesn't check, why does it feel the need to throw an Exception when a foldername ends with a space?

Comment: I think it should not be FileNotFound or DirectoryNotFound exception. It has something to do with Http request. I do not know more about it :-)

Comment: I don't suggest there should be a different kind of exception. I just wonder why they decided to throw an exception when a folder ends with a space but not when it starts with one. Thank you for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

[Setting up Visual Studio 2010 to step into Microsoft .NET Source Code](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/04/21/setting-up-visual-studio-2010-to-step-into-microsoft-net-source-code.aspx)

Using thing post I tried to find out what is actually haopping in .net framwork when we use method `server.MapPath` after debugging the .net framwork code I found out calls to get absolute path from virtual path going throw following files and methods of framework

**File** -
System\Web\httpserverutility.cs\1477467\httpserverutility.cs
**Method**-MapPath

**File** -
\System\Web\VirtualPath.cs\1477467\VirtualPath.cs**Method**-Create

**File** -System\Web\HttpRequest.cs\1599819\HttpRequest.cs
**Method**-MapPath

But i found that with the strage behaviour its returning me null when path is /folder1/folder2 /file.cs but not reutn null object when enter /folder1/ folder2/file.cs

I hop you like to step in framwork and see what happnen

Any way good question ..but still the anwser to this question might be given by microsoft people only who design that files in framewok

---

The problem is its not able to locate the Folder withg space i.e "Folder2 ".not valid and not able to locate this folder on file system.

Basically you dont find any folder on windows file system which is having sapce after namei.e at the end or begining.

Comment: But why does `'/folder1/folder2 /'` while `'/folder1/ folder2/'` doesn't? You can't create a folder that starts with a space either.

Comment: You get a null result? that's weird. So not a HttpException?

Comment: @MrSoundless - yes you can also check that by stepping in framework code..i pasted link in answer at top that will help you...

Comment: @MrSoundless - anyway I m going to delete answer tomorrow once i got quota to delete answer because its not solve your prob ...